# Disable notifications in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Is there are a way to disable all notifications in Visual Studio Community 2017?

I mean all of them, I never want to see that flag nagging me ever again.

[image: VS Notificiations Flag]

Comment: The ones that appear in the notification-window and make the flag-icon change its color.

Comment: User Notifications is a package identified by the guid {B89CD7D2-19DB-4B60-A958-E882AE71A66E}. What you can test is 1) create a registry key HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<15xxxx version>\Packages\{B89CD7D2-19DB-4B60-A958-E882AE71A66E} and 2) add an empty 'CodeBase' string value in it. <15xxxx version> must correspond to the current version of VS 2017 you use. Look other similar keys in the registry at the same level, in fact it could exist already (could be '15.0', or like '15.0_5e87da33' for example. Visual Studio won't be able to load it any more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This Visual Studio extension [Hide Notifications Flag (by Michal Žůrek)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=misaz.DisableNotifications) will hide the notifications flag.

> After installing this extension Visual Studio will not show
>   notifications flag in header next to feedback button. Notification
>   window with list of updates available will be still available in View > Notifications.
>
> This is useful if you do not want to install some updates and the
>   distinctive color of the background of the flag distracts you from
>   working.

Answer (score 2):

One may use a network monitor and firewall to disable access to all Microsoft servers... Provided you need to use network capabilities in the program at all (I do). If you don't need network, just block Visual Studio in Windows Firewall

Answer (score 1):

I have an extension to [Hide Sign in and Feedback buttons](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/extensions.html#hide_sign_in). To hide the notifications icon instead of the feedback icon, just change GetChild(o3, **1**) to GetChild(o3, **0**).

Answer (score -1):

1. Right click on the Visual Studio notification in the Notifications window and click "Always Ignore"
2. Left-click on the ReSharper "Pencil and paper icon" in the bottom-right corner and choose "Dismiss all notifications"

Comment: That requires me to do that for every notification. Which is exactly what I don't want to do.

Comment: Add to this, there is no longer an "Always Ignore" option (at least in VS2019).